# Nativescript label in stacklayout

Tags: nativescript

In my Nativescript application I need to display text in which one phrase has to be a clickable link. E.g.

For more information check out our **Privacy Policy**

In this case, Privacy Policy should a clickable link that would take the user to another screen where they can read the policy.

What is the best way to accomplish that?  I was thinking of using:

```html
<StackLayout orientation="horizontal" >
  <Label text="For more information check out our " textWrap="true" />
  <Label text="Privacy Policy" tap="showPolicy" />
</StackLayout>
```

However, if the first label's text is longer and wraps to a second line, the second label does not show.

I am missing something in the above code?  Is there a better way of achieving this?

Thanks.

EDIT:  This is what I am looking to achieve

For more information check out

our **Privacy Policy**

Where Privacy Policy needs to be a clickable link

Comment: How about using WrapLayout?

Comment: Sounds like you don't want a `horizontal` layout to me. Remove `orientation` from the StackLayout.

Comment: Reading over this again, you want a Grid. That wrapping in the stack is how the stacklayout should work in this case. You want a two column grid with those labels inside.

Comment: @BradMartin Brad,  I don't think the Grid would work because I need the first label's text to wrap naturally, spanning across the whole width.  The second should be following the first immediately regardless of the position.

Comment: @dashman This may work.  The label is now visible, but for some reason it is displayed below the first label. It looks like after wrapping the first label, the layout places the second label on a new line regardless of where the first text finishes.

Comment: It should move it to the new line only if there's no space. Don't forget sometimes the element is wider than you think (padding/margin etc). I suggest you set the backgroundColor of both labels differently - and find out the actual dimensions. Also the WrapLayout itself could have a padding - set the backgroundColor for it also.

Comment: @dashman Following your suggestion, I changed the background color and it turns out that after wrapping to the second line the first label takes up the whole second line regardless of how much text is in it.  In this case only about 10% of the line was used, but the whole line was reserved for the label.  The next label was moved on the 3rd line

Comment: I have created a ticket with the Telerik guys to ask about this behavior.  Meanwhile I tried using FormattedString, but I am still have some issues.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261311/nativescript-formattedstring-tap-event-on-a-span