# Nativescript FormattedString - tap event on a Span

Tags: nativescript

I have the following markup:

```html
<StackLayout paddingLeft="15" paddingRight="15" dock="top" >
  <Label textWrap="true">
    <Label.formattedText>
      <FormattedString>
        <FormattedString.spans>
          <Span text="By checking 'yes' I understand that this is a legally valid and binding written agreement, and I indicate that I have read, understand, and agree to the terms of my " />
          <Span text="Agreement. " foregroundColor="#3aba90" tap="viewAgreemnent" />
          <Span text="Also, by checking 'yes', I certify that I have read and agree to accept electronically the "  />
          <Span text="Privacy Policy." foregroundColor="#3aba90" tap="viewPolicy" />
        </FormattedString.spans>
      </FormattedString>
    </Label.formattedText>
  </Label>
</StackLayout>
```

This creates one text block with Agreement and Privacy Policy rendered in a different color.  The goal is when the user taps them to execute a function displaying the agreement or the policy.  The problem is that the tap event does not fire for the Spans.  Is this event even available at this level or only on the top Label level?

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Span` elements in NativeScript have no touch events, as you can read in the api documentation: https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_text_base_span_.span

There is however a pull request to implement such a feature: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/pull/8256

A workaround (note: I'm using nativescript-vue) for the meantime would be something like the following. While, obviously, far less than ideal, it will yield the desired result:

```html
<FlexboxLayout flexWrap="wrap">
    <Label text="I " />
    <Label text="accept " />
    <Label text="the " />
    <Label text="Terms of Service" textDecoration="underline" @tap="open('https://example.com')" />
    <Label text=" and " />
    <Label text="the " />
    <Label text="Privacy Policy" textDecoration="underline" @tap="open('https://example.com')" />
    <Label text="." />
</FlexboxLayout>
```

Here is the `open()` function to open the provided URLs in the browser:

```js
import * as utils from "tns-core-modules/utils/utils";

open(url) {
  utils.openUrl(url);
}
```

---

### Update June 2020:

Span elements now support the [linkTapEvent](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/__nativescript_core_.span#linktapevent). You can read the [test](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/da80cd5e1a710343373c4fbd1e1750a12b2fac7a/e2e/ui-tests-app/app/button/tappable-span-page.xml) to see how it is used. Unfortunately, I was unable to build a Playground Demo, yet.

Comment: This is my attempt to use the `linkTapEvent` in the Playground. Unless I made a stupid mistake, this should be working. I assume, the Playground is not using the latest NS version. However, a local build didn't yield any better results. Maybe I'm missing something here? https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=LS2rme&v=2

Answer (score 0):

You want to do

```xml
<Span 
  text="Privacy Policy." 
  foregroundColor="#3aba90" 
  tap="{{ $parents['Page'].viewPolicy }}" 
/>
```

https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding#binding-to-a-parent-binding-context

Comment: Thanks Rob.  This does not seem to work.  $parents['Page'] seems to be pointing to the bindingContext of the page and the actual method is not available at that context.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Ok,  I just confirmed from Telerik that Span does not derive from View and does not support any events.